# How to decide which layout to use?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used both Linear and Relative layout . But still don't know excatly when to use which .
How to decide which one to use ? Explain with some example .

Comment: I asked this question because i wanna know which one is best for performance . The answer i got is it depends on our need . We should have knowledge of every layout and we should also have knowledge of best practices of layout or how to optimize layout .   To read about layout optimization :[layout optimization](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html) and to read about layout we can use link provide in answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a personal preference for most of the cases.

You have to decide according to your necessity. You should however try to stick to `RelativeLayout`, if you are using multiple nested `LinearLayouts` since those can drop your performance noticeably.

See [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/07/android-layouts-linear-layout-relative-layout-and-table-layout/). You'll have a good idea about different layouts. Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This all depend on personal preferences and Experience matters a lot .
Personally i use combination of Linear layout in most of cases but sometimes FlowLayout and Relative Layout etc are used.

**Linear Layout** (vertical / Horizontal ) are used to create basic layout. Following  properties help create view better and esthetic .

```
android:Layout_weight
```

**Relative Layout** is used to create  overlay effect and  also used to relate position of different Views according to position . Following  properties help create view better and esthetic .

```
android:layout_margin
android:paddingLeft
android:paddingRight
android:paddingTop
android:paddingBottom
```

**Frame Layout** used to create Overlay layout like on option pressed  etc.
also Frame Layout Can used to create overlay ads .
[image: The Overlay view is created with Framelayout and gravity is set to right]

**Grid Layout** is used to create grid , you may have see gallery pics which are basically implemented in grid layout.
Example of Grid is Gallery Photos